# Wordpress Redirects 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We're having problems with redirects, we updated website to WordPress and now we're making old link redirects to new ones. Everything ended with this link:

```
Redirect 301 /lt/ytoj-konsult/43 /paslaugos/gydytoju-konsultacijos/kaune/endokrinologas/
```

When you go to this page `/lt/ydytoj-konsult/43` it redirects to `/paslaugos/gydytoju-konsultacijos/43` Page 43

But it should redirect to this `/paslaugos/gydytoju-konsultacijos/kaune/endokrinologas/`page.

How could we solve this problem?

Comment: Check for another rule, the one you have posted is not doing that

Comment: What you mean @123

Comment: I mean the rule you have posted here and the behaviour you describe do not match, therefore it is likely another rule is acting before this one.

Comment: Well there are other WordPress rules in access file. @123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` directive at top of your .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/lt/ytoj-konsult/43/?$ /paslaugos/gydytoju-konsultacijos/kaune/endokrinologas/
```

`Redirect` directive adds matching URI at the end of target URI.

Comment: Now it doesn't need to use 301 number? @anubhava

Comment: Surely you can add `301` now like this: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/lt/ytoj-konsult/43/?$ /paslaugos/gydytoju-konsultacijos/kaune/endokrinologas/` Default `302` is good for testing.

Comment: Added it like that: RedirectMatch 301 ^/lt/gydytoj-konsultacijos/41/?$ /paslaugos/gydytoju-konsultacijos/kaune/ortopedas-traumatologas/ but still it doesnt work :/

Comment: You mean it is showing 302 instead of 301? Tried clearing browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

Use this plug in for creating redirects. It will also show you where broken links are, it's a great plugin. This is a lot better than messing with your htaccess file. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/